# How to query/filter from Microsoft Graph all groups where a user is owner

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to query from Microsoft Graph all groups where a specific user is owner.
I tried the following query:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=owners/any(owner: owner/id eq '4dc60fe7-8009-4131-a4e9-80dc5e86f98f')`

Unfortunately this returns a 400.

Does anyone know the correct OData query? Or is this not even supported by MS Graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to filter on owners. The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group) states which properties can be `$filter`'ed.

Look for

> Supports $filter

in the description of each property.

You are going to have to read all groups, pull out their owners, and do the filtering client side.

Comment: Does that mean that filtering is not possible on any relationship?

Comment: I don't know if all relationships are not $filter-able, you would have to look at the docs for the ones you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The [memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof) endpoint returns all the groups of a given user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{ID or email}/memberOf
```

Will return:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
            "displayName": "The group name",
            "...":"...",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I believe the user was trying to list all groups where a specific user was an owner.  Unfortunately, `/memberOf` doesn't return the owners of each group returned.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [List ownedObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0) graph API to do that where it gets the list of directory objects that are owned by the user.

But as the question is specifically about getting the list of groups that a user is owner of, you can use the below graph API where it gets the list of directory objects with *odata.type* as **microsoft.graph.group**:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{User Object ID}/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.group
```

And if you just want to get the group name and group ID, you can use $select,

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{User Object ID}/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.group?$select=displayName,id
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get all groups with owners using single API call like this:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners
and then select groups which have current user in owners collection.